# latency in dispatching UDP packets through loopback interface?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ipc

I'm going to write a program that listens to an UDP port, and then dispatches the data to multiple server instances. The code of the server software has been structure to listen to a port itself, not to receive data from another program that runs locally. So my idea is basically to create a second UDP stream from the front-end program to the server instances through the loopback interface.
The application is latency critical, that is, the overhead shouldn't exceed 1 millisec. I'm wondering then if this is then the best approach or not: I fear that the packet would be scheduled again for another turn of dispatch by the kernel (linux in my case). If I'm right, will this latency be noticeable? If so, is the only solution to rewrite a new form of inter process communication between the front-end and the server application?

Comment: You can't just say "latency is critical". *How much* latency is too much? You would have to try it. I don't know what you mean by "UDP stream" either. UDP is not a stream,it is a sequence of packets.

Comment: by critical I mean that I don't want to have a drawback on responsiveness of more than 1 millisec. And about UDP stream, well, choose your synonym of preference: talk, conversion, exchange of packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduling is not really issue.  If a process or thread is waiting on `select()` or `recvmsg()` it should be awakened by an incoming datagram almost instantly.  (The sender gives up its CPU slice when it invokes `sendmsg()`, the kernel gets it to pass the message through the loopback, then the receiver will be higher than the sender in the scheduler.)

Latency through the loopback interface will be sub-millisecond, provided that the receiver is ready to receive.

Most of your latency will come from whatever each receiver is doing between reading packets off the socket.  For example, if a receiver needs 0.5 milliseconds of CPU time processing between receipts, then your latency is going to be about 0.5 milliseconds.  But if you are running 3 such receivers per CPU core, then your latency cannot be less than 1.5 milliseconds.